# Subgroups of a multiplicative group.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

The multiplicative group $G$ has eight elements $e, a, b, c, ab, ac, bc, abc$, where $e$ is the identity. The group is commutative, and the order of each of the elements $a, b, c$ is $2$.

1. State the orders of the elements $ab$ and $abc$.
2. Find four subgroups of $G$ of order $4$.
3. Give a reason why no group of order $8$ can have a subgroup of order $3$.

I don't know what happens to the orders of two elements when they're multiplied together, or how to create a group with order four, and I think the last question has something to do with Lagrange but I'm not sure. Basically I don't understand the question at all so any help would be really appreciated. Don't worry this is for revision not an assignment so don't be afraid to be super specific.

Thanks

Comment: Hint. The fact that the group is commutative should help you figure out the order of $ab$. (Lagrange will handle 3.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming multiplicative means abelian. If it doesn't, let me know, but I'm not sure what else it could mean.

1. $(ab)^2=a^2b^2=ee=e \implies |ab|=2$ and $(abc)^2=a^2b^2c^2=eee=e \implies |abc|=2$
2. $\langle a,b \rangle \leq G$, $\langle a,c \rangle \leq G$, $\langle b,c \rangle \leq G$, and $\langle a,bc \rangle \leq G$ all have order $4$.
3. It is precisely because of Lagrange. The order of any subgroup $\textbf{must}$ divide the order of the total group and obviously, $8$ does not divide $3$.

Let me know if you have questions on notation.

Comment: No. Multiplicative means the the group's operation is multiplicative. Commutative is the same as abelian.

Comment: But what is the difference than between a multiplicative operation and a non-multiplicative operation? Is it just a naming convention?

Comment: It seems to me that it's just to ensure the reader can make sense of the notation of the other elements. If you call an element 'ab' but the operation isn't concatenation then it opens up other weird interpretations.

Comment: The way it is written. If for a cyclic group we use the notation $\;\Bbb Z_n\;$ , most probably it is meant the group of residues modulo $\;n\;$ , with operation addition modulo $\;n\;$ , If instead we write $\;C_n\;$ , most probably we mean the *mutiplicative* cyclic group of  order $\;n\;$ for some generator $\;\{1, a, a^2,...a^{n-1}\}\;$ . A matter of convention, that's all.

Comment: But aren't both $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and $C_n$ abelian? $C_n$ is abelian b/c for any $g_1,g_2 \in C_n$, we can write $g_1=a^{k_1}$ and $g_2=a^{k_2}$, so $g_1g_2=a^{k_1+k_2}=a^{k_2+k_1}=g_2g_1$.

Comment: @Ben Yes, they are. In fact, they're isomorphic...so what? There are **many** multiplicative groups that are **not** abelian.

Comment: I guess I am wondering what the explicit definition for a multiplicative group is. Is it just that it uses multiplicative notation?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what it means. The OP could have written additive group as well, but should then write $g + h$ instead $gh $. Not that it matters for the question..

Answer (score 1):

If the order of an element $a$ is $n$ and $a^t=e$ then $n$ divides $t$. Indeed, we can write $t=qn+r$ for some $0\le r<n$ and then $e=a^{qn+r}=(a^n)^qa^r=e^qa^r=a^r$, so we have $a^r=e$. By the definition of order, $r=0$, so $t=qn$, as claimed.

For **commutative** groups, if $m$ and $n$ are respectively the orders of $a$ and $b$, then, let $k=\text{lcm}(m,n)$. Then $(ab)^k=a^kb^k=ee=e$. Then the order of $ab$ must be a divisor of $k$.

*This is not necessarily true if the group is not commutative*. (The identity $(ab)^k=a^kb^k$ only works in commutative groups, or more precisely, if the particular elements $a$ and $b$ commute).

To create a subgroup of order four, note that you must pick $e$ and, for the moment, another element. This new second element can't have an order greater than $3$ (otherwise, you would add too many elements, because if you add $a$ then you must also add $a^2$, $a^3$, etc), but the order of every element in $G$ is $2$ (or $1$ for $e$), so you can pick any one. Let's remain simple and pick $a$.

Now we have $e$ and $a$. Since $a^2=e$, $a$ is its own inverse, so $\{e,a\}$ is a subgroup. (This idea is important: if the order of $a$ is $n$, then $a^{n-1}$ is the inverse of $a$). Then we need another element. Let's add $b$. We have $\{e,a,b\}$. This is not a subgroup, because $ab$ is not in the set$^*$. Let's add it, then. Is $\{e,a,b,ab\}$ a subgroup?

To finish, no, a group with $8$ elemnts can't have a subgroup with $3$ elements, and this can be easily proved with Lagrange's theorem.

$(*)$: This is not as obvious as it may seem. You must prove that $ab$ is not $e$, $a$ or $b$. For example: $ab$ is not $e$ because $a^2=e$, so if $ab$ were $e$ then $a^2=ab$ and $a=b$, a contradiction with the description of the group. Could you prove that $ab$ is not $a$ or $b$?

*Remark*: I have proposed questions, but I don't really expect explicit answers. They are only to make you think.